# Python module loading everywhere but not in PyCharm

Tags: python, import, pycharm, anaconda, rasterio

I want to use the `rasterio` package for some Python script.
I use Anaconda an I have set up an own environment in which I'm working.

The problem is that `rasterio` imports fine everywhere but not in PyCharm.
When I use the Anaconda command prompt, activate my environment, run Python and type `import rasterio` it works. Also when I open a jupyter notebook, an import works.
However, when I try to import it in PyCharm, the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\oggm\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-4-7a1458fddb27>", line 38, in <module>
import rasterio
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.3\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\oggm\lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from rasterio._base import eval_window, window_shape, window_index
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.3\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
```

- even though I have chosen the Python executable of my environment as project interpreter. Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, the simple solution is to update the `gdal` package and then `rasterio` imports fine also in PyCharm...
I don't know why it worked for all other attempts.

Comment: its not working for me, rasterio is working fine in terminal but not in pycharm. I am also unable to add rasterio and gdal from project interpreter. Please help

Comment: Sorry, I haven't looked further into this - I'd give the issue a fresh reinstall and try it this way.